# Does the Outlook API have a method that returns a room’s capacity information?

Tags: office365api, outlook-calendar, outlook-api

Wondering if there is an Outlook API method that is available that can give us the room's capacity information?

Also, confirming that the only way to get a room's availability is to use the FindTime API?